# Changin content of FragmentB from FragmentA of a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I try to change a TextView from the DetailFragmentA in the DetailFragmentB from a ViewPager. Following it the code I tried to do that. But the App crashes with following LogCat if I press a Button to change the TextView in FragmentB. What can I do? Which a static variable it worked, but that's not a realy good solution.

This is my Activity and Adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity {
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    public Fragment detailFragmentA = new Fragment();
    public Fragment detailFragmentB = new Fragment();


    public static String saveText;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager(), detailFragmentA, detailFragmentB);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public  void refresh(String text){
        ((DetailFragmentB) detailFragmentB).changeText(text);   
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private Context _context;
        private Fragment fragmentA;
        private Fragment fragmentB;


        public MyAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, Fragment fragA, Fragment fragB) {
            super(fm);  
            _context=context;
            fragmentA = fragA;
            fragmentB = fragB;

            }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragmentA =DetailFragmentA.newInstance(_context);   
                return fragmentA;
            case 1:
                fragmentB=DetailFragmentB.newInstance(_context);    
                return fragmentB;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the FragmentA Class:

```
public class DetailFragmentA extends Fragment 
                                    implements OnClickListener{

    Button button;
    TextView textB;
    EditText edit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        DetailFragmentA f = new DetailFragmentA();  

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        textView.setText("Testing");
        button = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);      

        edit = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

     return root;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Test", "onClick");

        ((ViewPagerExample) getActivity()).refresh(edit.getText().toString()); 

    }
```

And this is the FragmentA:

```
public class DetailFragmentB extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
     String saveText = "default";

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        DetailFragmentB f = new DetailFragmentB();  

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_2, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsTextB);
        textView.setText(saveText);
        return view;
    }

    public void changeText(String editable){

        saveText = editable;
        textView.setText(saveText);
    }
}
```

But the App crashes with following LogCat if I press the Button to change the TextView in FragmentB. What can I do?

```
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at com.example.viewpagerexample.ViewPagerExample.refresh(ViewPagerExample.java:35)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at com.example.viewpagerexample.DetailFragmentA.onClick(DetailFragmentA.java:64)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-14 17:46:24.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit**
I changed to following in the class ViewPagerExample:

```
public Fragment detailFragmentA = new DetailFragmentA();
public Fragment detailFragmentB = new DetailFragmentB();
```

now I get a NullPointerExeception:

```
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at com.example.viewpagerexample.DetailFragmentB.changeText(DetailFragmentB.java:49)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at com.example.viewpagerexample.ViewPagerExample.refresh(ViewPagerExample.java:35)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at com.example.viewpagerexample.DetailFragmentA.onClick(DetailFragmentA.java:64)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-14 19:50:54.673: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast fragmentB as a detailFragmentB.  But it may not be a detailFragmentB, you initially set it equal to a new Fragment().  Change that to new DetailFragmentB.  Do the same for A, as I'm sure your have the same bug on it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me the code position were I should change it? Is it in the constructor of the MyAdapter class?

Comment: Its in the activity at the very top, in the declarations.      public Fragment detailFragmentA = new Fragment();
    public Fragment detailFragmentB = new Fragment();
Change those to the correct types.

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately now I get a NullPointerException (see my edit) when I press the Button to change the TextView. Have you an other ideaß

Comment: ChangeText is being called before onCreate for that fragment, so textView isn't initialized and an NPE occurs.  You can fix it immediately by adding a null pointer check, but you'll probably have more work to do to get it to work as you want.

Comment: Is there a better way to achive the change of the TextView?